# Showkeys: Omit optional argument of \label

Tags: cleveref, mathtools, showkeys

I use `cleveref` and `mathtools` together with the `showkeys` package. However, since for some labels I'm using my own type, labels can get pretty long (in the following example the label will be `[mytype]{mylabel}`.

I'd like to cut off the optional argument part as it does not contain any useful information.

Can I do this with the `showkeys` package? Apparently, there is no direct option for doing that and this is no issue if not loading the `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline=on, twoside, 11pt,
BCOR=4mm,
 captions=tableheading,
 draft
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label[mytype]{mylabel}
a=b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about your document setup. In particular, do tell us whether you load `cleveref` before or after `showkeys`.

Comment: Updated the question with a MWE.